# One of the Text views is not visible

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have this XML, inside Android Studio the TextView **tv_question_title** looks fine, but when I run the app the text is invisible. The rest of XML looks fine while running the app, also the TextView below it looks ok. What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#B2333333"
>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/white_part"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.75"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_question_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:fontFamily="@font/molde_regular_webfont"
    tools:text="Thanks for feedback"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/white_part"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_question_subtitle"
    android:fontFamily="@font/molde_regular_webfont"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="What can we do"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_question_title"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_improve_offer"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_question_subtitle"
    android:background="@drawable/border_improve_offer"

    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_error"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Error"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    app:layout_goneMarginStart="24dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="@color/red_design"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_question_title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_caffeine_info"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_question_subtitle"
    />



<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:fontFamily="@font/molde_regular_webfont"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
    app:cornerRadius="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_improve_offer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

    />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry for the repeat text, It would not let me to post the question without more text :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `tools` namespace with `android` namespace.

The `tools` namespace is used for design purpose and will only be shown on Android Studio design preview not when you run the app.

So replace this:

```
tools:text="Thanks for feedback"
```

With

```
android:text="Thanks for feedback"
```

You can learn more about `tools` name space from [this documentation link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes).

Comment: @Akiva glad to hear.. if that was helpful please accept the answer